# How do I map an array of objects, that also have an array of objects inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I am using TypeScript, and I am a bit of a newbie to it.
I have an array like so, but the keys in 'orderBreakdownList' ("8" & "upward-trending") will be unknown to the app every time it loads.

```
{
  "userId": "00bdad66",
  "totalNumberOfOrders": 5,
  "totalNumberOfPackages": 54521,
  "totalNumberOfItems": 13,
  "totalNumberOfDeliveredOrders": 3,
  "totalPrice": 39409.0,
  "orderBreakdownList": [
    {
      "8": {
        "noOfItems": 1,
        "noOfPackages": 17160,
        "id": 8,
        "totalPrice": 3741.52,
        "orderItems": [
          {
            "upward-trending": {
              "tag": "upward-trending",
              "value": 6653.16,
              "price": 18798.89,
              "id": 76
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to render out the 'orderBreakdownList' array that have objects inside it, and render the second array into a list. (Drop down table with single item data)

his is what I tried so far,

```
<div>
      {orderBreakdownList.map((items, index) => {
        return (
          <ol key={index}>
            {items.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
              return <li key={sIndex}> {subItems} </li>;
            })}
          </ol>
        );
     })}
</div>
```

But I am not getting this to work, nor get any data out of it. Maybe I need another map into it?
I need some help, please.

EDIT:
As per @rantao 's suggestion I came up with the following code. Using only html without CSS framework.

```
<div>
      {orderBreakdownList.map((orderBreakdown, i) => {
        const keyName = Object.keys(orderBreakdown);
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            Order number: {keyName}
            {Object.values(orderBreakdown).map(
              (
                { noOfItems, noOfPackages, id, totalPrice, orderItems }: any,
                i
              ) => {
                return (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <div>Id: {id}</div>
                    <div>Nr. of items: {noOfItems}</div>
                    <div>Nr. of packages: {noOfPackages}</div>
                    <div>Total price:{totalPrice}</div>
                    <ul>
                      {orderItems.map((item: any) =>
                        Object.values(item).map(
                          ({ tag, value, price, id }: any) => (
                            <li key={id}>
                              <div>Id: {id}</div>
                              <div>Tag: {tag}</div>
                              <div>Value: {value}</div>
                              <div>Price: {price}</div>
                            </li>
                          )
                        )
                      )}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: `items` isn't an array so you can't map it.  `items` (better called `item`) is the individual element within orderBreakdownList array.  The individual element I see has a single property `8` with an object as its value, and that object has orderItems property.  So you'd need, instead of `items.map`, `items.8.orderItems.map`.  Not sure what that 8 is, it looks like a code smell.

Comment: You can't map over `items` as its an object.

Comment: @James OP said that `8` and `upward-trending` will be unknown, so you cannot explicitly do `items.8.orderItems` because the key is not known. See my answer, which utilizes `Object.values` and `Object.entries` to mitigate this constraint.

Comment: @rantao sure, point was "don't map over items it's not an array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "second array", you're referring to the `orderItems` inside the `orderBreakdownList` array. In that case, you would do something like this:

```
<div>
  {orderBreakdownList.map(orderBreakdown => (
    <ol>
      {Object.values(orderBreakdown).map(({ orderItems }) => (
        orderItems.map(item => (
          Object.values(item).map(({ tag, value, price, id }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              <div>{tag}</div>
              <div>{value}</div>
              <div>{price}</div>
            </li>
          )) 
        ))
      ))}
    </ol>
  ))}
</div>
```

The `Object.values()` takes the values of the object without having to explicitly define the keys - `8` and `upward-trending` in this case. If you want to know what the key is, replace `Object.values()` with `Object.entries()` which returns an array of  tuples that contains the `key` and `value` of the object.

For example:

```
Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => {
 // Map nested item
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed and clear answer, many "cudos". I find arrays to be fun, but complicated. 
What if I want to render both the keys value, and the objects? Should I then run Object.value() on the parent array? (The number 8 in this case)

Comment: No problem! In that case, use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.values`. An example is already in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`items` is an object and you can get the sub items by retrieving the object keys. Then you can improve on that from there

```
<div>
      {orderBreakdownList.map((items, index) => {
       let keyName = Object.keys(items);
        return (
          <ol key={index}>
              <li> {items[keyName]} </li>;
          </ol>
        );
     })}
</div>
```